# ngResource some resource for multiple URI's

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

I have some URI's which are sending some stats about a resource:

```
/web/1/stats/views
/web/1/stats/sells
/web/1/stats/instock
```

How can I use ngResource with those URI's without creating functions for each of them? Ideal will be to have a resource '/web/:webID/stats/' and then append `view, sells, unstuck`, or maybe there is a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a 'category' parameter in the URI: `/web/:webID/stats/:category` you could then either pass in the category when you make the reqeust e.g.

```
statsResource.query({ category: 'views' });
```

or define different actions for the resource, setting the category parameter to the appropriate value:

```
// inside resource factory method
return $resource('/web/:webID/stats/:category', null, { queryViews: { method: 'GET', params: { category: 'views' } });
```